# POS tagging not consistent using Spacy en_core_web_lg model

Tags: nlp, spacy, pos-tagger, dependency-parsing

- POS tagging for PROPN **not working** in an expected manner using the **en_core_web_lg** model.
- POS tagging works more predictably using the **_md** model.

Given the (poorly-formed) sentence:
*"CK7, CK-20, GATA 3, PSA, are all negative."*

When using the _lg model, "CK7" is tagged as a NOUN(NNS).

When using the _md model, "CK7" is tagged as a PROPN(NNP). **This is correct.**

When using the **_lg** model, and replacing "CK7" in the sentence for:

- "CK1" tagged as PROPN
- "CK2" tagged as PROPN
- "CK3" ,"CK4" tagged as PROPN
- "CK5" tagged as **ADJ**
- "CK6" tagged as PROPN
- "CK7" tagged as **NOUN**
- "CK8" tagged as PROPN
- "CK9" tagged as **ADP**
- "CK22", "CK222",  tagged as  PROPN

When using the *_md* model, and replacing "CK7" as described above, all were tagged PROPN, **as expected**.

As **most** of the sentences I will be analyzing will be **poorly** formed, I thought that the **_lg** model's 'deeper' **dependency parsing** would serve better, only to find the above issues with **POS tagging**.

Please advise on:

1. How to deal with the counter-intuitive POS tagging when using the en_core_web_lg model?
2. Which model is best for dependency parsing poorly-formed sentences?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Pos tagging is very context dependent. Try writing the same sentence but substituting just the one work then review the pos

Comment: @Nathan - that is exactly what I did in my posted question.

Comment: Oh I see. I believe you will have to make a exception in the tokenization and pos if this is representative of your text. I'll try to post an answer to do this

Comment: What version of spacy are you using?

Comment: @aab - 2.0.1 all validated.

Answer (score 2):

So this is not a direct answer to your question, but if you are working with biomedical data it might make sense to try out this package:
[scispacy](https://allenai.github.io/scispacy/)

It doesn't tag CK-7 as a proper noun, but it can handle lots of these kinds of terms as entities, see the various additional NER models that support different tagsets. It's still under development and you might still need to add special cases/exceptions for your data, but I think you will see better and more consistent results than with the standard spacy models.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll check this out.